# How can I insert a word inside a command in Linux?

Tags: bash, apt, gitpod

Now, I have a simple file that runs every time I open my Gitpod(cloud env). I am making a file so that I can access it via ngrok. But, I need some packages, like wget, unzip and neofetch(for my ease). But it opens in a *different* terminal and I have to enter <kbd>y</kbd> every time. Is there a way to put y in the command and it will install automatically?

Source code for the file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update

sudo apt install wget unzip openssh-server neofetch -y

sudo service ssh start

echo "Set Password for Gitpod as gitpod"

sudo passwd gitpod

wget "https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip"

unzip "ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip"

echo "I need your ngrok auth token. Enter it below."

read -p "ngrok authtoken:" authtoken

./ngrok authtoken $authtoken

echo "Authtoken activated, now activating server..."

./ngrok tcp 22
```

> sudo apt install wget unzip openssh-server neofetch -y

Have I put correctly in this line? If this works, whenever I get a cloud environment, it could just install all deps and go ahead.

Output:
NOT an answer, an output.

The fish shell I like and use's output:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type `help` for instructions on how to use fish
gitpod@ws-588be66f-373e-46f0-8342-5d39b8c863f4 /w/coder-lg-blog-codedoc (master)> sh .gitpod/ngrok.sh
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                           
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                         
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                                                 
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:7 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal InRelease      
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
107 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
.gitpod/ngrok.sh: 5: y: not found

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

Yeah its a cloud Gitpod env for my blog and I want SSH tunneled via ngrok but it says this:

> /repo > .gitpod/ngrok.sh: 5: y: not found

How can I fix this? The mod deleted the last output so please don't delete this! It is mainly an output of the Gitpod Terminal.

Comment: **1** Don’t use `apt` in scripts; use `apt-get`. **2** `apt-get` can be run non-interactively, just RTFM or ask your favourite search engine. **3** Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: yo @Biffen it doesnt work. it is a shell script btw

Comment: _What_, exactly, doesn’t work? Yes, it’s a shell script…?

Comment: apt-get, it comes with the same error.

Comment: What error is that? Did you add any options to make it non-interactive? Could you [edit] the question to include the `apt-get` command that you tried, as well as the error you get?

Comment: edited again  and added a commit [`here`](https://github.com/im-coder-lg/coder-lg-blog-codedoc). ShellCheck says all is good but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please don’t link to code on external sites; [edit] the question to include the _actual_ code.

Comment: That error doesn’t look like the result of the code in the question. Are you running the strange suggestion in one of the answers; `| y`? That won’t work. Have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install).

Comment: yeah yeah, about the code, I hate EXTENDED paragraphs, its a pain for the reader/answerer so I linked it. PS: It's Gitpod, so I have to commit it.

Comment: works, I am marking this as answer, and am giving credit to all the people who helped here!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please don't delete.

By @Biffen and this is the solution!

> That error doesn’t look like the result of the code in the question. Are you running the strange suggestion in one of the answers; `| y`? That won’t work. Have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install).

Thanks to everyone who helped here, and I am marking this as answer, because Biffen's reply was a comment.

Edit: In 2 days as of now, I can mark this as answer, because, Stack Overflow said so.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `echo` command in your script and use this as a standard input for your next command.

`echo y | [next-command]`